# Jump over a row at intervals when dragging down a formula

Tags: excel, excel-2010

i want to drag down the below formula into row, sum the first 46 rows but i want it to skip four rows (jump over it not delete).

the formula I have is SUM(OFFSET(B$3,(ROW()-3)*46,0,46,1))....
but this keep summing every 46 rows

Comment: so you want to sum B3:B48, then then next row to sum B52:B97?

Comment: exactly @Scott Craner

Comment: Change the `*46` to `*49`

Comment: Just an FYI:  Offset is Volatile, Use `=SUM(INDEX(B:B,(ROW(A1)-1)*49+3):INDEX(B:B,(ROW(A1)-1)*49+48))`

Comment: Thanks.. but its still adding up the rows i want it to skip or jump

Comment: What is the formula you tried?

Comment: i actually want something like sum B3:B48 retain B49:B51 for the next four rows then sum B52:B97

Comment: That is not what your question above is asking.  You will need a second formula for that.

Comment: Oh ...Okay.. pls assist

Comment: I have given enough explanation in my answer for you to modify to get the second formula.

Comment: pls can you help to modify it. its my core challenge 'how to retain the rows its not adding in the answer'

Answer (score 1):

For sake of answering.  Using `OFFSET()` the jump is determined by the `(ROW()-3)*46`.  By changing the `*46` to the correct jump of `*49` it will skip the desired rows:

```
=SUM(OFFSET(B$3,(ROW()-3)*49,0,46,1))
```

But that is volatile.  Volatile functions calculate every time Excel calculates whether the data to which the formula points changes or not.  By using INDEX to create the range we can avoid the volatility:

```
 =SUM(INDEX(B:B,(ROW(A1)-1)*49+3):INDEX(B:B,(ROW(A1)-1)*49+48))
```

Same thing here the `*49` is the jump and the `+3` is the starting row of the first group and the `+48` is the ending row of the first group.

Both formula will sum the following ranges as it is dragged down: `B3:B48`,`B52:B97`,`B101:B146`,`B150:B195`,`B199:B244`

---

As per the comments use this formula:

```
=SUM(INDEX(B:B,INT(ROW(B1)/2)*49+MOD((ROW(B1)-1),2)*2+(ISODD(ROW(A1))*48)):INDEX(B:B,INT(ROW(B1)/2)*49+MOD((ROW(B1)-1),2)*2+(ISODD(ROW(A1))*48)))
```

Which now returns the sums of (`B3:B48`,`B49:B51`,`B52:B97`,`B98:B100`,`B101:B146`,`B147:B149`) as it is filled down.